# What does "sdl6" in an RPM package name refer to?

Tags: linux, rpm, trac

The specific package I'm referring to is trac-1.0.1-1.sdl6.noarch.rpm. According to this page:

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-file-format.html

it seems to be part of the package release version. The fact that "sdl" does not appear in my /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc file also suggests that it's not related to the architecture.

If you search google for sdl6, just about every hit is the name of an RPM package. Nowhere, however, could I find an explanation of what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the distro tag (for CentOS normally `el#`). In this case `sdl` appears to be for [Springdale Linux](http://springdale.math.ias.edu/).

Comment: Thank you. Although I couldn't verify that independently, that seems to be a correct assumption.