# What does kb stand for in an rpm name?

Tags: linux, centos, 32bit-64bit, rpm

I'm replacing a 32 bit package with the equivalent 64 bit package.

The 32 bit package name is: gdal-1.4.2-4.el5.i386.rpm

The 64 bit package name is: gdal-1.4.2-4.el5.kb.x86_64.rpm

These packages are for CentOS5 (32bit) and Centos6 (64bit) respectively.

I've googled all over the net, read various articles about rpm naming conventions, and grep'd the contents of /usr/lib/rpm/

But I still can't find what 'kb' stands for in the 64 bit package name, and therefore don't know if I should be concerned or carry on regardless.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "sdl6" in an RPM package name refer to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542804/what-does-sdl6-in-an-rpm-package-name-refer-to)

Answer (score 1):

Going back to the original rpm download link I note it says 'from KBS Extras Testing repository' underneath the link to the rpm.

So I believe I've partially answered my own question, but could someone confirm 'kb' in the rpm name does indeed indicate it's part of the 'KBS Extras' packages?

If this assumption is correct, this poses some new questions. What are the 'KBS Extras' packages? What's so 'Extra' about them? And what does 'KBS' stand for?

Comment: Yes, it's a reference to [Karanbir Singh](http://wiki.centos.org/KaranbirSingh), leader of the CentOS project. He usually signs off as "KB". I don't know if that's a normal shorthand for Karanbir, or if there's a middle initial B in there.

Comment: Thanks Etan and Warren, I would never have guessed Karanbir (B) Singh would be what 'kb' stood for.